# MDL-menu does not work with mustache

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, material-design-lite

I have main page of website and i load content with `ajax` request in scroll event. I use `mustache.js` for adding mdl - cards. And i want to add mdl - menu to cards. First `ajax` load wihout scrolling is work. But after scrolling, in added cards `mdl-menu` does not work. Why?

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-  phone">
  <div class='demo-card-wide demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp'>
    <div class='mdl-card__media' ></div>
    <div class='mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand' style="background: url('{% templatetag openvariable %} image {% templatetag closevariable %}') center / cover;">
      <h2 class='mdl-card__title-text'> {% templatetag openvariable %} title {% templatetag closevariable %} </h2>
    </div>
    <div class='mdl-card__supporting-text'>
      {% templatetag openvariable %} description {% templatetag closevariable %}
    </div>
    <div class='mdl-card__menu'>
      <div class="mdl-button--floating-action" style="position: relative; left: 45px; bottom: 35px;">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-ripple-effect" id="{% templatetag openvariable %}id{% templatetag closevariable %}">
          <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
          <span class="mdl-ripple"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="{% templatetag openvariable %}id{% templatetag closevariable %}">
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">
            Share
            <div class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored">
              <i class="material-icons">share</i>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">
            Delete
            <div disabled class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored">
              <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border'>
      <a class='mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect' href='/posts/{% templatetag openvariable %}id{% templatetag closevariable %}'>
        Подробнее
      </a>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer" align="center"></div>
      <div class='mdl-card__supporting-text' align="right">{% templatetag openvariable %} pub_date {% templatetag closevariable %}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, what can i do?